# Automatic changing recycling bin icon?

Tags: windows-7

Is there some way I could make the icon on the recycling bin change once it became so full?
I have no idea how to script anything but I gave it a try and I don't really think this'll work but here's what I came up with:
[autorun]
icon=recyclingbin1 if < 1mb
icon=recyclingbin2 if > 1mb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You over-thinking the problem :)
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Change-how-the-Recycle-Bin-looks

Comment: He doesn't want it to be based off of **if** there are recycled items, but the **size** of recycled items. If he has 500 1KB files he deleted, he wants it to appear full, but if he has 500GB of files that he's deleted, he wants it to display a 3rd image, perhaps a **BULGING** recycle bin.

Comment: ah, my mistake. I didn't read the 'so full' part correctly.

Comment: Apparently that bit didn't matter after all, since that was a quick accept.